# UITableView rows not reloading with UITableViewRowAnimationNone

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView and in its `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method I want to change the appearance of two cells (the one that has just been selected and the one that was selected before). I do that with this method:

```
// reload both rows to change appearance
if (![indexPath isEqual:activeIndexPath]) {
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:activeIndexPath, indexPath, nil]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}
```

With the parameter `UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic` set it works great: the corresponding rows are updated with a smooth transition. But I want those two rows to update immediately without an animation.

I thought that `UITableViewRowAnimationNone` would do the trick but if I use that constant for the row animation the cells are not being updated at all

Comment: What are you changing? The dataSource ?

Comment: No, the cell's `backgroundView`.

Comment: How ? What do you do that changes the background view ?

Comment: In the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method I change my custom cell's property `cell.active = YES;`. In my UITableView sublass I have implemented the setter method for this property:
`- (void)setActive:(BOOL *)active {
    ((CBTrackCellBackgroundView *)self.backgroundView).highlighted = active;
    [((CBTrackCellBackgroundView *)self.backgroundView) setColors];
    [self.backgroundView setNeedsDisplay];
}`
I know it's a rather unclean solution but it should still work.

Comment: Ok, but what I mean is, in didSelectRow are you simply reloading the table view row ? How does your cellForRowAtIndexPath know which row to now show as selected?

Comment: That part is rather complicated: Every row in my `tableView` corresponds to a profile. One of those profiles is the *active* profile which is stored in a singleton manager. In the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method I check if the row's profile equals the *active* profile and if true I mark the cell as active.

Comment: does the flow go within the `if(![indexPath isEqual:activeIndexPath])` block? try enclosing the `-reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` within `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` (_just suggesting..._) if not then post some more code that you have in your `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method